# When using cloud-init, is it possible to both specify a boot script and a data blob that can be queried from inside the instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data, cloud-init

I have some current instances that get some data by passing a json blob through the user data string. I would like to also pass a script to be run at boot time through the user data. Is there a way to do both of these things? I've looked at cloud-config, but setting an arbitrary value doesn't seem to be one of the options.

Comment: UserData is executed sequentially, is there any problem in doing one and then the other? You could load the script from S3 or just specify it in the UserData directly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. There does not seem to be a way to pass more than one user data string. Can you be more specific about what you're suggesting?

Comment: Are you using cloud-init now to pass the json data?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that on EC2, there is only one 'user-data' blob that can be specified.  Cloud-init addresses this limitation by allowing the blob to be an "archive" format of sorts.

- [Mime Multipart](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html)
- Cloud-config Archive

cloud-config archive is unfortunately not documented now, but there is an example in [doc/examples/cloud-config-archive.txt](https://github.com/number5/cloud-init/blob/master/doc/examples/cloud-config-archive.txt).  It is expected to be yaml and start with '#cloud-config-archive'.  Note that yaml is a strict superset of json, so any thing that can dump json can be used to produce this yaml.

Both of these formats require changes to all consumers to "share" the shared resource of user-data.  cloud-init will ignore mime types that it does not understand, and handle those that it does.  You'd have to modify the other application producing and consuming user-data to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `cloud-init` [supports multi-part MIME](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html). With that in mind you could have your boot script as one part, then a custom mime part. Note that you would need to write a python handler that tells `cloud-init` what to do with that part (most likely moving it to wherever your app expects it). This handler code ends up in the handlers directory as [described here](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/dir_layout.html).